# space after ui-view but nothing to do with CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

Ok, this is a strange one.
I asked a question before about this, but I mistook this for a CSS issue but it appears to be something to do with ui-router / ngRoute (As this was happening before I switched to ui-router).

I was getting an issue with spacing which I mistook for a child margin issue.
So here is my html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <!-- Keep the scale and disable zoom -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />

    <link href="content/foundation/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/foundation/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/angular-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="content/core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test" metro>
    <div>
        <nav class="top-bar" role="navigation">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <h1><a ui-sref="home">Test site</a></h1>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <section class="profile right" profile></section>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <section class="page" ui-view></section>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mm-foundation-tpls-0.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <script src="app/common/common.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/api/handler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/models/models.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/options/options.js"></script>

    <script src="app/components/components.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/metro/metro.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/tiles/tiles.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/profile/profile.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/draggable/draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/loadingButton/loadingButton.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/backgroundSwitcher/backgroundSwitcher.js"></script>

    <script src="app/home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="app/error/error.js"></script>
    <script src="app/account/account.js"></script>
    <script src="app/account/stock/stock.js"></script>
    <script src="app/security/security.js"></script>
    <script src="app/security/profile/profile.js"></script>
    <script src="app/customerServices/customerServices.js"></script>
    <script src="app/customerServices/viewOrder/viewOrder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I commented out all the css file and was still getting the issue. The spacing problem appears between the **ui-view** and the child page. 
An example of a child page is this:

```
﻿<div class="row slide-in-right">
    <section class="tile-column large-2 columns" id="{{ container.id }}" ng-repeat="container in controller.menu" tile-column>
        <h1 class="column-title">{{ container.name }}</h1>
        <a class="tile box-shadow {{ tile.classes }}" id="{{ tile.id }}" ui-sref="{{ tile.action }}" ng-repeat="tile in container.tiles" coloured-tile="{{ tile.colour }}" tile>
            <i class="fa {{ tile.icon }}"></i>
            <span class="title">{{ tile.name }}</span>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

I tried removing all the HTML (except one div inside the ui-view) using chrome developer tools and the problem still remained.
If I look at the dev tools, I can see this:

[image: ui view spacing issue]

As you can see, the highlight bit shows the space that seems to be included.
If I edit the HTML I can see this:

[image: Editing space issue]

If I remove that red dot, the spacing issue goes away.
I have no idea what is causing it.
Does anyone else?

Comment: Please set up a plunker demonstrating the issue

Comment: may be the template file for row slide-in-right have UTF-8 BOM.